# How to retrieve column value for a specific date and compare them with the most recent date before it?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a query that retrieves devices readings based on multiple joins. Here's the simplified query:

```
SELECT devices.name,
       devices.type_id,
       devices_readings.device_id,
       ROUND(CAST(devices_readings.reading AS numeric), 2) AS reading,
       devices_readings.reading_slot_time
FROM devices
INNER JOIN devices_readings ON devices.id = devices_readings.device_id
AND devices.type_id = 289
AND devices_readings.reading_slot_time::date = '08-19-2020'
AND devices.place_id = 1;
```

This query retrieves readings for a specific date for each device_id, and what I need now is to get the most recent date before the specific date for each sensor (which could be 2, 3, 4, or 5 days ago) and compare the readings to calculate the change in the value (+ or -).

I have tried retrieving all data and then limiting it by the number of devices, but I'm not satisfied with this approach. Is it possible to accomplish this task in a single query? If so, how can I modify my query to achieve this given that the devices_readings table contains 1-2 millions of data and is partitioned by month?

And here's the expected input and output based on the query I want to modify I added them to the fiddle below based on comments suggestions

[Fiddle Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/VrzZQsqf)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Update your post with sample input data and expected output.

Comment: @lemon I tried to add the expected output i want to modify the query to achieve it. Thanks

Comment: Start with this:  `select *, lag(reading) over (partition by device_id order by reading_slot_time) as previous_reading from devices_readings;`

Comment: @MikeOrganek actually this is the first time I find about lag() Thanks, but what i found that lag works on its previous row, it won't work with a query like this as there is one reading per this day `select *, lag(reading) over (partition by device_id order by reading_slot_time) as previous_reading
from devices_readings
where reading_slot_time::date = '08-19-2020' and device_id = 786`

Comment: Without the input and the actual output it is impossible to determine why your query is producing incorrect results or your expectations are perhaps off. Please update your question to contain input data and actual output and table DDL, as text - **no images**. Even better create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk). Also, explain the contention that `lag(reading) ...` does not work, as getting previous reading regardless of date is exactly what it does.  Unless you are claiming you have multiple readings on the same day for a device. In which case you need to update the question to indicate that.

Comment: @Belayer i created this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VrzZQsqf)  hope it can explains a bit please let me know if more info needed

Answer (score 0):

Read PostgreSQL's documentation on *window functions* to understand what I do here below. PostreSQL supports *named windows*; as the same partitioning and ordering is needed three times, I create a named window (`WINDOW w AS ...)` and use it in the `LAG()` functions.

I just put the data you used in your provided dbfiddle into two WITH clauses for illustration

```
WITH devices (id,type_id,name,component_type_id,place_id) AS (
          SELECT 1,1,'device 1',7,1
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1,'device 2',7,1
UNION ALL SELECT 3,1,'device 3',7,1
UNION ALL SELECT 4,1,'device 4',7,1
)
,
devices_readings (id,device_id,reading,read_at,reading_slot_time) AS (
          SELECT 1,1,49,DATE '2022-03-15',DATE '2022-03-15'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,1,50,DATE '2022-03-18',DATE '2022-03-18'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1,48,DATE '2022-03-12',DATE '2022-03-12'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,1,25,DATE '2022-03-11',DATE '2022-03-11'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,1,30,DATE '2022-03-01',DATE '2022-03-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 5,2,50,DATE '2022-03-18',DATE '2022-03-18'
UNION ALL SELECT 6,2,45,DATE '2022-03-15',DATE '2022-03-15'
UNION ALL SELECT 7,2,40,DATE '2022-03-12',DATE '2022-03-12'
UNION ALL SELECT 8,2,44,DATE '2022-03-10',DATE '2022-03-10'
UNION ALL SELECT 9,2,50,DATE '2022-03-01',DATE '2022-03-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 10,3,10,DATE '2022-03-18',DATE '2022-03-18'
UNION ALL SELECT 11,3,20,DATE '2022-03-17',DATE '2022-03-17'
UNION ALL SELECT 12,3,20,DATE '2022-03-15',DATE '2022-03-15'
UNION ALL SELECT 13,3,12,DATE '2022-03-14',DATE '2022-03-14'
UNION ALL SELECT 14,4,5,DATE '2022-03-13',DATE '2022-03-13'
UNION ALL SELECT 15,4,30,DATE '2022-03-11',DATE '2022-03-11'
UNION ALL SELECT 16,4,20,DATE '2022-03-10',DATE '2022-03-10'
)
SELECT 
  name
, type_id
, device_id
, reading::numeric(18, 2) AS reading
, read_at
, reading_slot_time
, lag(reading) OVER w AS previous_reading
, lag(read_at) OVER w AS previous_reading_date
, reading - lag(reading) OVER w AS reading_diff
FROM devices
JOIN devices_readings ON devices.id = device_id 
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY read_at)
ORDER BY device_id , read_at;
   name   | type_id | device_id | reading |  read_at   | reading_slot_time | previous_reading | previous_reading_date | reading_diff 
----------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------------------+--------------
 device 1 |       1 |         1 |   30.00 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-01        |                  |                       |             
 device 1 |       1 |         1 |   25.00 | 2022-03-11 | 2022-03-11        |               30 | 2022-03-01            |           -5
 device 1 |       1 |         1 |   48.00 | 2022-03-12 | 2022-03-12        |               25 | 2022-03-11            |           23
 device 1 |       1 |         1 |   49.00 | 2022-03-15 | 2022-03-15        |               48 | 2022-03-12            |            1
 device 1 |       1 |         1 |   50.00 | 2022-03-18 | 2022-03-18        |               49 | 2022-03-15            |            1
 device 2 |       1 |         2 |   50.00 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-03-01        |                  |                       |             
 device 2 |       1 |         2 |   44.00 | 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-10        |               50 | 2022-03-01            |           -6
 device 2 |       1 |         2 |   40.00 | 2022-03-12 | 2022-03-12        |               44 | 2022-03-10            |           -4
 device 2 |       1 |         2 |   45.00 | 2022-03-15 | 2022-03-15        |               40 | 2022-03-12            |            5
 device 2 |       1 |         2 |   50.00 | 2022-03-18 | 2022-03-18        |               45 | 2022-03-15            |            5
 device 3 |       1 |         3 |   12.00 | 2022-03-14 | 2022-03-14        |                  |                       |             
 device 3 |       1 |         3 |   20.00 | 2022-03-15 | 2022-03-15        |               12 | 2022-03-14            |            8
 device 3 |       1 |         3 |   20.00 | 2022-03-17 | 2022-03-17        |               20 | 2022-03-15            |            0
 device 3 |       1 |         3 |   10.00 | 2022-03-18 | 2022-03-18        |               20 | 2022-03-17            |          -10
 device 4 |       1 |         4 |   20.00 | 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-10        |                  |                       |             
 device 4 |       1 |         4 |   30.00 | 2022-03-11 | 2022-03-11        |               20 | 2022-03-10            |           10
 device 4 |       1 |         4 |    5.00 | 2022-03-13 | 2022-03-13        |               30 | 2022-03-11            |          -25
```

Here is what you need to do if you need both a `LAG()` result and a filter by date applied:

```
WITH
all_rows AS (
  SELECT 
    name
  , type_id
  , device_id
  , reading::numeric(18, 2) AS reading
  , read_at
  , reading_slot_time
  , lag(reading) OVER w AS previous_reading
  , lag(read_at) OVER w AS previous_reading_date
  , reading - lag(reading) OVER w AS reading_diff
  FROM devices
  JOIN devices_readings ON devices.id = device_id 
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY read_at)
  ORDER BY device_id , read_at
)
SELECT 
  * 
FROM all_rows
WHERE read_at='2022-03-11'
;
   name   | type_id | device_id | reading |  read_at   | reading_slot_time | previous_reading | previous_reading_date | reading_diff 
----------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------------------+--------------
 device 1 |       1 |         1 |   25.00 | 2022-03-11 | 2022-03-11        |               30 | 2022-03-01            |           -5
 device 4 |       1 |         4 |   30.00 | 2022-03-11 | 2022-03-11        |               20 | 2022-03-10            |           10
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I use condition by a date adding `where read_at = '2022-03-11' ` it shows the previous reading with null although there is reading at 2022-03-10

Comment: I attempted to use the row_number() function to filter the query in the provided dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/hZEwvhM7). However, I noticed that it returned rn = 1 for device 4, which seems incorrect. I'm curious about why this is happening, but I don't want to simply add an extra condition after the query.

Comment: The `WHERE` filter is applied before the window function. With that filter, you have no previous row to pick a value from. Hence NULL. If you want to get a value in your `LAG()` function, you need to run the query without filter in a sub select, and query that sub select with the filter you want. I just added something to my response to show that